# How to find all instances of certain text pattern and add them to an array in PHP?

Tags: php, string, explode

For example, I have this text:

```
<content>Foo</content>This is only a <b>test</b><content>Bar</content>Again, only a test.
```

How can I create an array with two entries, `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: are you trying to get everything in <content> tags?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to add all the content of all the content tags to an array

Comment: You write about tags, so this is HTML, right? You are aware that text in HTML can be written in many different ways? `<!-- <content> --> This is only a <b>test</b><content>Bar</content>` for example.

Comment: I am using the Twitter API, so I am assuming it will be pretty normalized and standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/<content>(.+?)<\/content>/is", $string, $matches);
```

Your results will be put into the `$matches` array.

Access them with `$matches[0]`, `$matches[1]`, and so on.

Good luck!

EDIT: `preg_match_all()` will give you all of the results! Thanks to @Blake for the tip.

Comment: You actually want `preg_match_all` otherwise you will only get the first match.

Comment: Wait did you mean to write "is" in that line? What is that for?

Comment: It works. Look [here](http://www.wmtips.com/php/regular-expressions-made-easy.htm) and go to "Using in PHP." It matters!